# What is this component? What is its purpose?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, adafruit, nrf52832

What is this component?

[image]

[image]

I don't how to search for it. It has only "4 4" written on it; I didn't get any search results from it.

Does anyone know what this SMD component is, and what it is used for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a ceramic chip antenna, and it does what antennas usually do.

Its specs (but not its make and model) are in chapter 7 of the module's [datasheet](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/040/357/original/MDBT42Q-Version_B.pdf?1490125904) which can be found on Adafruit's website.

Maybe with this information you can google make and model, or find a similar one.

Answer (score 7):

https://www.adafruit.com/product/3406?amp&amp check this video out. It explains every single compenents on it. So, according to video, it is the antenna.

Comment: Specifically https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btIo90M4vlE